# Which one is correct between 'I have interest in which is' and 'I have interest which is'?

Tags: american-english

I not sure about the following sentence whether correct or not.

> "I have interest in which is a developing your plan."

Also what if I remove the 'in' from above sentence, Is that also correct as the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to say, but I suppose either of the following:

> I have *an* interest in developing your plan.

If you change *interest* to a verb, you could say:

> I **am interested** in developing your plan.

Without using "in", you could say:

> I have an interest which is developing your plan.

This is a combination of the phrases *I have an interest* and *which is developing your plan*.

*interest* as used is a noun, so an article is needed. Also no article before the verb *developing* (maybe that was a typo?).

Comment: Thanks than what is difference above your sentence and 'I am interested in'? Is this same meaning with your sentence?

Comment: I added an example to my answer. Both mean roughly the same thing as I understand your phrases (other contexts might be different).